# Conditionally attach behaviors to craft\elements\Entry by section

Tags: plugin-development, entries, modules

I'm trying to conditionally attach behaviors based on an entries section.

The following code works fine, but I'm trying to clarify one bit:

To avoid a `yii\base\InvalidConfigException` on the CP entries screen, I need to bail early with the `$event->sender->sectionId` check.

Should I be using this event for this type of thing?

…or should I attach them later, e.g. `PopulateElementEvent`?

```
<?php

namespace modules\appmodule;

use Craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\events\DefineBehaviorsEvent;
use Tightenco\Collect\Support\Collection;
use yii\base\Event;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    const SECTION_BEHAVIORS = [
        'products' => [
            \modules\appmodule\behaviors\Reviewable::class,
            \modules\appmodule\behaviors\Product::class,
        ],
        'trips' => [
            \modules\appmodule\behaviors\Reviewable::class,
            \modules\appmodule\behaviors\Trip::class
        ],
    ];

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        Event::on(
            Entry::class,
            Entry::EVENT_DEFINE_BEHAVIORS,
            function (DefineBehaviorsEvent $event) {
                $event->behaviors = Collection::make(self::SECTION_BEHAVIORS)
                    ->filter(function ($behaviors, $sectionHandle) use ($event) {
                        return
                            $event->sender->sectionId &&
                            Craft::$app->sections->getSectionById($event->sender->sectionId)->handle === $sectionHandle;
                    })
                    ->prepend($event->behaviors)
                    ->flatten()
                    ->all();
                }
          );
    }
}
```